# Spring Invocation order of @Bean and @PostConstruct in a @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am have a configuration class set up like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
   private String field1;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       field1 = < system property >
   }

   @Bean
   MyService myService() {
       // initialize MyService and use field1
   }
}
```

And I am wondering if the init() method will always run before the myService() method, since the myService() method relies on init running to set the value of some system property.

I know that I could just initialize field1 in myService(), but I am interested in what would happen in the exact scenario shown above.

Comment: why are you "wondering"? why not _try it_?

Comment: and if that is a system property, that is absolutely the wrong way to read it.

Comment: The order is always the same. Google Bean-Lifcycle and check the pictures.

Comment: @Eugene have tried it. It works, but we have had things before like circular dependencies where our app would work fine with them and then it just randomly failed to start one day. Was trying to see if anyone knew the configuration order